# How do I get the Scala version from within Scala itself?

Tags: scala, version

This is not about command-line compiler options. How do I programmatically obtain the Scala version inside code?

Alternatively, where does the Eclipse Scala plugin v2 store the path to `scalac`?

Comment: The Scala IDE for Eclipse does not store a path to `scalac`; it invokes the compiler classes directly from within with Eclipse JVM.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet Thanks, btw, I've found that `scala.sys.props` references what seems to be scala libraries under something like `sun.boot.class.path -> F:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\316\1\.cp\lib\scala-library.jar;` (with `jar`'s `library.proerties` containing `version.number=2.9.0.final`). But since `scala.sys.props` is in there since `2.9.0` only it's pretty much a hint itself :)

Comment: Damn, someone, please make this a wiki! :)

Comment: ..heck, this is going to get 100 upvotes this year, probably, let's keep pushing, folks
(who'd have known Scala is so convoluted that even things that simple may puzzle ya).

Comment: Here we go, folks, here we go.

Comment: What's the purpose of these comments of yours?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet To summon a true professional who'd know their way around the SO UI to turn this into a community wiki, of course -- but let me know if you were suspecting something else :)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

This will work without access to `scala-compiler.jar`:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> util.Properties.versionString
res0: java.lang.String = version 2.9.1.final
```

Comment: I had to add scala as spark libraries were loaded first. So `scala.util.Properties.versionString`

Comment: On Scala 3 this will print the standard library version which is shared between 2 and 3 and has version 2.x
eg: Scala library version 2.13.8 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

Answer (score 62):

There are three ways to get the Scala version -

```
scala> util.Properties.versionNumberString
res103: String = 2.11.4

scala> util.Properties.versionString
res104: String = version 2.11.4

scala> util.Properties.versionMsg
res105: String = Scala library version 2.11.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Comment: The first one is nicest of all on this page, seemingly :)

Comment: FYI `util.Properties.versionNumberString` only exist since scala 2.10.x. For scala below 2.10.x, you can use `util.Properties.releaseVersion.getOrElse("unknown version")` to get version number string.

Answer (score 18):

You can get the Scala version like this:

```
scala> scala.tools.nsc.Properties.versionString
res7: java.lang.String = version 2.9.0.final
```

I don't know the specifics of the plugin, though.

Comment: I think you can use the `scala.tools.nsc.Properties.versionString` anywhere.

Comment: On `import scala.tools.nsc.Properties;` mine says "object tools is not a member of package ***.scala" :(

Comment: `scala.tools...` is only available, if the `scala-compiler.jar` is in the classpath.

Answer (score 11):

We can also get installed Scala version

1. Open command prompt
2. type Scala
3. You will get following output:

Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_6
0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.