# How to retrieve Scala's version in REPL?

Tags: scala

When trying to run some code in online interpreters or with IRC bots, I always wonder which version of Scala they support.

Is there a way to retrieve the version of Scala from within the interpreter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the Scala version from within Scala itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121403/how-do-i-get-the-scala-version-from-within-scala-itself)

Comment: This question is 10 years old and I left Scala half a decade ago?
But yes, both questions have correct answers.

Comment: I actually didn't write that comment myself, I only suggested a duplicate via the SO UI ^^ (and it seems SO generated the comment).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For Scala 2, use `scala.util.Properties.versionNumberString` (or `versionString`):

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.versionString
val res0: String = version 2.13.6

scala> scala.util.Properties.versionNumberString
val res1: String = 2.13.6
```

For Scala 3, if you do the same thing, you may be surprised by the answer:

```
% scala3 -version
Scala code runner version 3.0.1 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL
% scala3
scala> scala.util.Properties.versionNumberString                                                                              
val res0: String = 2.13.6
```

That's because Scala 3.0.x uses the Scala 2 standard library as-is, to aid migration, and makes only a small number of additions. (Eventually the standard libraries will no longer remain synchronized like this.)

Here's how to get the Scala 3 compiler version:

```
scala> dotty.tools.dotc.config.Properties.simpleVersionString
val res0: String = 3.0.1
```

This only works if the scala3-compiler JAR is on your classpath. (In the standard Scala 3 REPL, it is; in some other environments, it might not be.)

If the compiler isn't on your classpath and you want the full Scala 3 version string, see [Dmitrii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68588177/86485).

If the compiler isn't on your classpath but you just want to find out at runtime whether you're on Scala 2 or 3, well... perhaps there's a cleaner/better way, you tell me, but one way that works is:

```
util.Try(Class.forName("scala.CanEqual")).isSuccess
```

Here, the choice of `scala.CanEqual` is arbitrary, it could be any of the small number of classes that are in scala3-library but not scala-library.

But if you are tempted to go that route, you might instead consider including version-specific source in your project, or passing the Scala version via [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo).

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.versionMsg
res: String = Scala library version 2.9.0.1 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

Looks of course like the *library* version and not like the *language* version, but I think currently there won’t be a real difference in practice.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the exact Scala 3 version, you can read it from the Manifest file 
`.../scala3-library_3-3.0.1.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

```scala
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream

val scala3LibJar = classOf[CanEqual[_, _]].getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.toURI.getPath
val manifest = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(scala3LibJar)).getManifest
manifest.getMainAttributes.getValue("Implementation-Version")
```

Example in Scastie:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you need just the version number without the "version" keyword you can use `versionNumberString` function.

```
scala> scala.util.Properties.versionNumberString
res1: String = 2.12.3
```